# StreamReader, StreamWriter - what reference library do I need? How do I get the code below to work?

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

```
Sub UseStreamReader ()

    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    fileReader =
    My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\\testfile.txt")
    Dim stringReader As String
    stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
    MsgBox("The first line of the file is " & stringReader)`enter code here`

End Sub
```

Comment: None.  If you have to ask then you probably used a UWP project template.  It forces all file operations to be async, so can't use StreamReader.

Comment: What project template did you select? Even if you selected Windows Forms, if you're targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework then the My namespace is probably not available.

Comment: I notice that you have several questions on VBA. Is this a VBA project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is easier:

```
Sub UseStreamReader ()

    For Each line in File.ReadLines("C:\testfile.txt")
      MsgBox("The line of the file is " & line )
    Next line

End Sub
```

ReadLines reads incrementally; if you stop before it's read the whole file, it didn't read the file into memory. This is in contrast to `File.ReadAllLines` which reads it all and returns you an array

These are all (including your code) in the `System.IO` namespace. You need to have a reference to System (every project should have this) and a line at the top of the class that says

```
Imports System.IO
```

If you dont have the imports statement you'll have to fully qualify every use:

```
For Each line in System.IO.File.ReadLines...
```